# Getting multiple screen buffers from swap-chain

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, dxgi

I want to create multiple render target view and i tried it but i can't get buffer more than 2.

I've already set DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC's BufferCount value as BufferSize

```
UINT const BufferSize = 4;
ID3D11Texture2D* BufferTemp;

ID3D11RenderTargetView** RenderTargetView = new ID3D11RenderTargetView*[BufferSize];
```

```
for (UINT i = 0; i < BufferSize; i++) {
    ZeroMemory(&BufferTemp, sizeof(BufferTemp));

    SwapChain->GetBuffer(i, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**)&BufferTemp);

    Device->CreateRenderTargetView(BufferTemp, 0, &RenderTargetView[i]);
}
```

In the actual code, I've initialized HRESULT value, and it said S_OK at the first loop, but after that it said 0x887a0001.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this swap chain is using `DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD` effect then `GetBuffer` method can only access the first buffer. That is you can only get view of the only buffer you can draw on.